# getView shown wrong position - ListView Android

Tags: android-listview

This is my source code. getView shown wrong position. I already searched solution for that on google but no success. Please help me.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final Phonebook entry = listPhonebook.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_row, null);
        convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View mycurrentListItemView,
                    MotionEvent event) {

                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.i("List item clicked position : ", "" + position);
                    Log.i("Name::Mail", "" + entry.getName() + " :: "
                            + entry.getMail());
                    mycurrentListItemView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                            .parseColor("#38ACEC"));
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    mycurrentListItemView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                            .parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListView is recycling the views with the convertView, so it only sets up the onTouchListener the first time the views are created (because of `if (convertView == null)`.

If you want this solution to work, you have to move the `convertView.setOnTouchListener()` call outside of the `if (convertView == null)` condition.
This way it will be initialized every time a view is displayed on the screen with your proper Phonebook entry.

Comment: Same problem for me, and this comment helped me out, thanks! (+1)